# Spring JPA is fetching the wrong IDs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have a LAN Spring Boot API that interacts with a LAN MySQL database, and I have 7 fields pertaining to user posts (not posted by user at the moment, I locally put in test data into the database): `id`, `posted_by`, `date_posted`, `title`, `description`, `amount_of_goons`, `amount_of_edges`.

The id is a randomly generated UUID using the `uuid()` function in MySQL and is the primary key.

In Spring Boot, I have a function in my PostRepository class used to fetch a post via ID. Originally, this worked with the function below. I then began to use RequestEntitys for responses, and my code stopped working, so I reverted the change and it CONTINUED not to work

```
package dev.JD.skibidibookapiwithdb.repository;

import dev.JD.skibidibookapiwithdb.model.UserPost;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Example;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.FluentQuery;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Function;


@Repository
public class PostRepository
{
    // custom Exception
    // if I were to use RequestEntitys I would not use this Exception for fetchPost()
    public static class PostNotFoundException extends Exception
    {
        public PostNotFoundException(UUID postID)
        {
            super("ID: " + postID + " Not Found");
        }
    }

    // DBService is an interface extending JpaRepository
    private final DBService postRepository;

    public PostRepository(DBService postRepository)
    {
        this.postRepository = postRepository;
    }



    public UserPost fetchPost(UUID postID) throws PostNotFoundException {
        Optional<UserPost> userPostOptional = postRepository.findById(postID);

        if (userPostOptional.isPresent())
        {
            return userPostOptional.get();
        } else {
            throw new PostNotFoundException(postID);
        }
    }


    public Integer changeGoonCount(UUID postID, int changeBy) throws PostNotFoundException {
        UserPost userPost = fetchPost(postID);

        userPost.setAmountOfGoons(userPost.getAmountOfGoons() + changeBy);
        postRepository.save(userPost);

        return userPost.getAmountOfGoons() + changeBy;
    }

    public Integer changeEdgeCount(UUID postID, int changeBy) throws PostNotFoundException {
        UserPost userPost = fetchPost(postID);

        userPost.setAmountOfGoons(userPost.getAmountOfGoons() + changeBy);
        postRepository.save(userPost);
        return userPost.getAmountOfGoons() + changeBy;
    }
```

...............bunch of delegate methods

When I use this method in my controller, the PostNotFoundException is thrown despite using an ID from the database. When using postRepository.findAll(), the IDs are different to the ones in my database. For example, id=31373864-3131-3663-2d65-3966652d3131 is returned by Spring despite the database ID being 178d116c-e9fe-11ee-8155-0800270e348d. This happens for every db entry, new or old and all other info is returned fine.

My DBService is very simple:

```
package dev.JD.skibidibookapiwithdb.repository;

import dev.JD.skibidibookapiwithdb.model.UserPost;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.UUID;

@Service
public interface DBService extends JpaRepository<UserPost, UUID> 
{
    
}
```

My controller is as follows:

```
package dev.JD.skibidibookapiwithdb.controller;

import dev.JD.skibidibookapiwithdb.model.UserPost;
import dev.JD.skibidibookapiwithdb.repository.EntityManagerRepository;
import dev.JD.skibidibookapiwithdb.repository.PostRepository.PostNotFoundException;
import dev.JD.skibidibookapiwithdb.repository.PostRepository;
import jakarta.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.UUID;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/posts")
public class PostsController
{
    private final PostRepository postRepository;

    public PostsController(PostRepository postRepository, EntityManagerRepository entityManagerRepository)
    {
        this.postRepository = postRepository;
    }


    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public String findPost(@PathVariable("id") UUID id)
    {
        try
        {
            return postRepository.fetchPost(id).toString();
        }
        catch (PostNotFoundException p)
        {
            return "Post Not Found";
        }
    }
}
```

and my user post model is as follows:

```
package dev.JD.skibidibookapiwithdb.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class UserPost {

    // this @Id means the field MUST be db primary key. UUID id MUST stay as the primary key
    // if pk changes this annotation must also change and be reallocated
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID id;
    private String postedBy;
    private String datePosted;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private int amountOfGoons;
    private int amountOfEdges;

    public UserPost() {
        // Default constructor
    }

    public UserPost(UUID id, String postedBy, String datePosted, String title, String description, int amountOfGoons, int amountOfEdges) {
        this.id = id;
        this.postedBy = postedBy;
        this.datePosted = datePosted;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.amountOfGoons = amountOfGoons;
        this.amountOfEdges = amountOfEdges;
    }

    // Getters and setters

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPostedBy() {
        return postedBy;
    }

    public void setPostedBy(String postedBy) {
        this.postedBy = postedBy;
    }

    public String getDatePosted() {
        return datePosted;
    }

    public void setDatePosted(String datePosted) {
        this.datePosted = datePosted;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getAmountOfGoons() {
        return amountOfGoons;
    }

    public void setAmountOfGoons(int amountOfGoons) {
        this.amountOfGoons = amountOfGoons;
    }

    public int getAmountOfEdges() {
        return amountOfEdges;
    }

    public void setAmountOfEdges(int amountOfEdges) {
        this.amountOfEdges = amountOfEdges;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        UserPost userPost = (UserPost) o;
        return amountOfGoons == userPost.amountOfGoons && amountOfEdges == userPost.amountOfEdges && id.equals(userPost.id) && postedBy.equals(userPost.postedBy) && datePosted.equals(userPost.datePosted) && title.equals(userPost.title) && description.equals(userPost.description);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, postedBy, datePosted, title, description, amountOfGoons, amountOfEdges);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserPost{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", postedBy='" + postedBy + '\'' +
                ", datePosted='" + datePosted + '\'' +
                ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                ", amountOfGoons=" + amountOfGoons +
                ", amountOfEdges=" + amountOfEdges +
                '}';
    }
}
```

It is probably useful to note that I orginally had the id in the UserPost model in the constuctor as this (I have since removed this, seeing no change):

```
public UserPost(String postedBy, String datePosted, String title, String description, int amountOfGoons, int amountOfEdges) {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID();
        this.postedBy = postedBy;
        this.datePosted = datePosted;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.amountOfGoons = amountOfGoons;
        this.amountOfEdges = amountOfEdges;
}
```

I have attempted all of the following: @GeneratedValue annotation to IDENTITY and AUTO, and fully removing it, using the database ID and Spring's (wrong) ID (both give Post Not Found responses), flushing postRepository, testing newly put-in database entries